# How can I get the image of the scanned fingerprint on my android phone?

Tags: android

We are working on a project on fingerprint door unlock system.But instead of using a fingerprint sensor ,I want to use the fingerprint sensor of my phone.How can I get the image of the fingerprint scanned?Image implies that I just want to use the phone just get the image of the fingerprint entered.

Comment: What do you imply by 'image' here ?

Answer (score 0):

Buy an external fingerprint reader — one that works with Android and has an SDK that gives you fingerprint data — and use that.

The Android fingerprint APIs specifically do not expose this sort of data to apps.